# Error con button y tabla en PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

No tabla open in php , imagen where error :
[image]

Me podran ayudar a encontrar el prooblema
Cuando trato de abrir la tabla, me habre el codigo, no me lo convierte en la tabla que necesito, la cual ya estaba funcionando solo le agregue la query de $result para hacer la validacion y ya no sale, me podran ayudar con cual sera el error.
Gracias amigos programadores.

```
<?php
    require '../../session.php';
    include("../../conexion.php");

    $con = new conec();
    $cnx2 = $con->conectar();
    $acreedor=$_POST['acreedor'];
    $importe2=$_POST['importe2'];
    $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];

 $result = pg_query($query = "SELECT SUM(Cast(importe as numeric(15,2))) as Total
                FROM cxpgastos
                    Where acreedor = '1040200'");
                if (!$result) {
                  echo "Ocurrió un error.\n";
                  exit;
                }

                while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {

                    if ($row[0]+$importe2 >= 15000.00)


                    echo "Supera El Limite De Gasto Anual";

                      else
                          echo "Seleccion Gasto No Deducible";


                }


     if( $tipo == "1" )
        $query = "select id_tipogasto, btrim(descripcion) as nombre, deducible from emb_tiposdegasto   where deducible = 'S' order by id_tipogasto;";
    else
        $query = "select id_tipogasto, btrim(descripcion) as nombre, deducible from emb_tiposdegasto   where deducible = 'N'  order by id_tipogasto;";

    $Cat = pg_query($query);





    ?>

<table id="tbTipos" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="5%" scope="col">ID</th>
                <th width="10%" scope="col">Descripcion</th>
                <th width="5%" scope="col">Deducible</th>

                <th width="1%" scope="col" align='center'>Acciones</th>


            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <?php          $id=0;
                        while ($bancos = pg_fetch_object($Cat))
                        {

                            if ($numfila == 0){ $class = "alt"; $numfila = 1; } else { $class = ""; $numfila = 0; }
                                echo "<tr class'".$class."'>";
                                echo "<td align='center'>".$bancos->id_tipogasto."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$bancos->nombre."</td>";
                                echo "<td align='center'>".$bancos->deducible."</td>";
                                //echo "<td align='center'>"."<a href=javascript:datosTipos('".$id."') rel='tipsy' title='Seleccionar'>
                                //<input type='radio' name='radio'/></a></td>";
                                echo "<td align='center'>"."<a href=javascript:datosTipos('".$id."') rel='tipsy' title='Seleccionar'>
                                              <img src='../../img/seleccionar.png' id='sel' style='vertical-align: text-top; height: 18px;'/></a> </td>";

                                echo "</tr>";
                                $id=$id+1;
                        }
                        pg_close();

          ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>     </tfoot>
</table>
```

Cual sera el problema en mi codigo ya que no logro encontrar el error, de que al hacer click en vez de abrir la tabla me sale el codigo de la tabala, aqui les deje todo mi codigo espero me ayuden y muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué extensión tiene el archivo donde te ocurre eso? ¿Dónde lo estás desplegando?

Comment: Es .php, ya funcionaba la tabla nomas le agregue lo del $result para valir si el monto es mayor a 15000 y de ese mensaje, y ahora no sale la tabla solo sale el codigo , todo el codigo que puse es ese

Comment: ¿Dónde estás desplegando el archivo .php? ¿Tienes indicado el DOCTYPE al principio del archivo y los meta, o ya los tienes desde otra parte?

Comment: comenta esa parte y vuelve a probar para descartar si se ha desconfigurado algo porque esta muyyy raro y pon 15000 si los ceros decimales en el **if**

Answer (score 0):

*[Esta respuesta es temporal, cuando el usuario coloque mas información se ira editando]*

He comentado todo lo que sean conexiones. Si realmente lo despliegas en un servidor php y el código es este, no deberias tener errores de los que comentas.

Este es mi resultado y el código editado. *[sin conexiones e required claro :P]
[abajo del todo]*

Tambien he probado a aplicar solo parte que dices que te ha causado el error, pero no parece haber nada visible.

```
$row[0]=13000;
$importe2=1000;
$importe3=15000.00;
if ($row[0]+$importe2 >= $importe3){
    echo "Supera El Limite De Gasto Anual";
}else{
    echo "Seleccion Gasto No Deducible";
}
echo $importe3;
echo ($row[0]+$importe2);
```

Prueba a colocar este código en tu servidor a ver si salta algo.
Despues vete metiendole las conexiones y los required.
Puede que el fallo no este aqui sino de los datos que recibes de la bbdd.

```
<?php
    /*require '../../session.php';
    include("../../conexion.php");

    $con = new conec();
    $cnx2 = $con->conectar();
    $acreedor=$_POST['acreedor'];
    $importe2=$_POST['importe2'];
    $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];

    $result = pg_query($query = "SELECT SUM(Cast(importe as numeric(15,2))) as Total FROM cxpgastos Where acreedor = '1040200'");
    if (!$result) {
      echo "Ocurrió un error.\n";
      exit;
    }

    while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
        if ($row[0]+$importe2 >= 15000.00){
            echo "Supera El Limite De Gasto Anual";
        }else{
            echo "Seleccion Gasto No Deducible";
        }
    }

    if( $tipo == "1" ){
        $query = "select id_tipogasto, btrim(descripcion) as nombre, deducible from emb_tiposdegasto   where deducible = 'S' order by id_tipogasto;";
    }else{
        $query = "select id_tipogasto, btrim(descripcion) as nombre, deducible from emb_tiposdegasto   where deducible = 'N'  order by id_tipogasto;";
    }

    $Cat = pg_query($query);
    */
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="tbTipos" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="5%" scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th width="10%" scope="col">Descripcion</th>
                    <th width="5%" scope="col">Deducible</th>
                    <th width="1%" scope="col" align='center'>Acciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th width="5%" scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th width="10%" scope="col">Descripcion</th>
                    <th width="5%" scope="col">Deducible</th>
                    <th width="1%" scope="col" align='center'>Acciones</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <?php          
                    $id=0;

                    $bancos->id_tipogasto = "it1";
                    $bancos->nombre = "Gasto altisimo";
                    $bancos->deducible = 0;

                    //while ($bancos = pg_fetch_object($Cat))
                    //{

                        if ($numfila == 0){ 
                            $class = "alt"; 
                            $numfila = 1; 
                        } else { 
                            $class = ""; 
                            $numfila = 0; 
                        }

                        echo "<tr class'".$class."'>";
                        echo "<td align='center'>".$bancos->id_tipogasto."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$bancos->nombre."</td>";
                        echo "<td align='center'>".$bancos->deducible."%</td>";
                        echo "<td align='center'><a href=javascript:datosTipos('".$id."') rel='tipsy' title='Seleccionar'><img src='../../img/seleccionar.png' id='sel' style='vertical-align: text-top;height: 18px;'/></a> </td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        $id=$id+1;
                    //}
                    //pg_close();
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si esa es mi duda tambien , no encuentro error en la sintaxis ni nada, pero probare tu code y te aviso, gracias

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro, pero creo que te falta incluir la conexión en la función **pg_query**

```
$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT...
```

---

Ejemplo de la web oficial de PHP http://php.net/manual/es/function.pg-query.php

```
<?php

$conn = pg_pconnect("dbname=publisher");
if (!$conn) {
  echo "Ocurrió un error.\n";
  exit;
}

$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT author, email FROM authors");
if (!$result) {
  echo "Ocurrió un error.\n";
  exit;
}

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo "Author: $row[0]  E-mail: $row[1]";
  echo "<br />\n";
}

?>
```